# What analysis would need to be conducted for a 0 - 100 scale

Tags: spss

Most guidance on scale analysis in SPSS I find is focused solely on Likert Scales, my study didn't use one however and instead used a 0 - 100 scale. Which analysis is best suited for this?

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack-Overflow! This isn't a programming question, and is therefore off topic here. You shold try to post it [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead. In any case, almost any analysis you can perform on likert scale values (except for frequencies for example) is good, and mostly better, with continuous variables.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.